# Unify interface and result

Tags: oop

I have 3 different interfaces to find an item, the result of these methods are also different.
My goal is to unify the interface as well as the result.

The current uml diagram looks like:
[uml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcQ4L.jpg)

Does anyone have a suggestion or any other kind of feedback?